# Submit in the same HTML/PHP page without jQuery/Ajax, is iFrame is the only option?

Tags: php, html, forms, iframe, submit

I want to make the output of a `<form>` in the same page of submit, I did it with html `<iframe>`, is there any alternative besides jQuery and Ajax?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're wanting to submit a form to the page it's currently on, is that correct?

Comment: Do you care if the page reloads?

Answer (score 1):

If you leave the "action" attribute of the `form` tag empty it will be submitted to the same page. You can then check to see if the form has been submitted and process the page accordingly.

Maybe something like:

```
<?php
 if($_POST['submitted']){
  echo "I have been submitted";
echo "<br/>";
  echo $_POST['text_input'];
}
?>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="text_input">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitted">
</form>
```